# How to Get Arrays Separately from JSON Objects in Rest

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

Lately i have been trying to consume a Rest service which returns the below rough sample JSON. It has objects which contains Arrays and arrays contains Strings.

```
    {
   Main Object:{

      Object1:{
           }
      Object2:{
           }
      Object3:{
               Array1[String1,String2,String3]
               Array2[String1,String2,String3]
               Array3[String1,String2,String3]
               Array4[String1,String2,String3]
               }

    }}
```

My requirement is to get all the arrays and check which of the specific array contains specific/required String values and than get those strings to show in jsp.

I am using Spring MVC(Rest Template) but any java based solution would do the work.

P.S: I am New to WebServices.

Comment: Have a go yourself first and then post your code here so that we can try to help you fix it.

Comment: i have been trying Jackson, GSON, Java core and all tutorials i found on google but nothing worked for this situation.

Comment: I just need few lines of code by which i can just get the arrays separated, rest  i know how to filter data once arrays are separated properly.

Comment: The number of objects (Object1, Object2) is fixed ? or it may change between calls ?

Comment: It may change, in fact there is lot of nesting.

Comment: Depending upon my search there can be thousands of arrays. And each array contains some strings, based on those i have to choose one result(Array).

Answer (score 1):

use JSONArray to get it from below

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonArray = JSONObject.getJSONObject("Main Object").getJSONObject("Object3").getJSONArray("Array1");
```

//Iterate through the above array to get required String.

**for the next array :**

```
jsonArray = JSONObject.getJSONObject("Main Object").getJSONObject("Object3").getJSONArray("Array2");
```

//Iterate through the second array to get required String.